# SQL Statement from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, operator-keyword

i am not a "pro" in SQL.

I have the following scenario:

Table: favcolor

```
 User   |Red    |Blue   |Yellow |Green  |Black
 Klaus  |0      |1      |1      |0      |0
 Jessy  |1      |0      |1      |0      |1 
 Andy   |1      |1      |0      |0      |0 
 Alex   |0      |0      |0      |1      |1 
 Denis  |1      |1      |0      |0      |1
```

The HTML code

```
 <form method="post" action="./usercolor.php"> <input type="checkbox" id="colorred" name="colorred" value="1" />red</td>
 <input type="checkbox" id="colorblue" name="colorblue" value="1" />blue</td>
 <input type="checkbox" id="coloryellow" name="coloryellow" value="1" />yellow</td>
 <input type="checkbox" id="colorgreen" name="colorgreen" value="1" />green</td>
 <input type="checkbox" id="colorblack" name="colorblack" value="1" />black</td>
 <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" /> </form>
```

PHP/SQL (using MySQL 5.6):

```
    $colorred       =   $_POST["colorred"];
    $colorblue      =   $_POST["colorblue"];
    $colorgreen     =   $_POST["colorgreen"];
    $coloryellow    =   $_POST["coloryellow"];
    $colorblack     =   $_POST["colorblack"];

SELECT * FROM favcolor WHERE red = '".$colorred."' AND blue = '".$colorblue."' AND green = '".$colorgreen."' AND yellow = '".$coloryellow."' AND black = '".$colorblack."'
```

Now to my problem:
For example i want to know which user like the color yellow. Then i check the checkbox on id "coloryellow" and press "SEARCH".
But i receive no results, because the "AND" operator in the SQL statement is wrong... 
Which operater i have to use that my SQL statement give me the two results?

Comment: Consider normalising your design

Comment: You'd need to create your WHERE clause depending on what checkboxes are checked. (Take a look at @cyadvert s answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$whereArr = Array();
if (isset($_POST["colorred"]) && $_POST["colorred"]==1) $whereArr[] = "red=1";
if (isset($_POST["colorblue"]) && $_POST["colorblue"]==1) $whereArr[] = "blue=1";
if (isset($_POST["colorgreen"]) && $_POST["colorgreen"]==1) $whereArr[] = "green=1";
if (isset($_POST["coloryellow"]) && $_POST["coloryellow"]==1) $whereArr[] = "yellow=1";
if (isset($_POST["colorblack"]) && $_POST["colorblack"]==1) $whereArr[] = "black=1";

$sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM favcolor WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $whereArr);
```

And then you run the query